# Console logging from a Firefox add-on

Tags: firefox, logging, console, firefox-addon, mozilla

The Mozilla documentation (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/console.html) says that I should use `console.log` to generate messages from an extension. Those messages are said to appear in the Firefox Error Console. But this is not the case for me. I'm using the Addon builder for the first time today, and I'd like to create an extension that switches tabs on certain events. The tabs are indeed switched, and to a tab which I expected, so my code definitely runs. But the console.log output is nowhere to see.

I have set the filter to "All". All I see are CSS warnings from the addon builder itself.

I have also installed Firebug. It doesn't show anything, too. (This works fine when using console.log from the context of a web page though.) The problem with Firebug would be that it's only enabled for one/some tab anyway, so when switching tabs, it's useless. I need a log window that's always there.

So where will the output from console.log end up?

Comment: Are you using console from Firefox->For web developers->Error Console (Ctrl+Shift+J)?

Comment: Yes, exactly that with the same hotkey. The one directly from Firefox, which has always been there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go ahead and put a test `console.log("something")` in your addon `main()`;

If nothing shows up in the Error Console ('Messages' tab), then maybe Firefox isn't configured to show `console.log` (happened recently with jetpack sdk 1.14).  See: [Changes to console.log behaviour in SDK 1.14](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/03/27/changes-to-console-log-behaviour-in-sdk-1-14/) for details.

Quick and dirty summary: In `about:config` set `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel` to `"all"`

Although from your question:

> I have set the filter to "All".

... it sounded like your were already aware of this.  So it's not entirely clear what you meant by that.

Comment: I've only set the filter with the buttons that are available in the error log window, not with a hidden setting. But from the article you referenced, the new default would be "error", which only prints calls to console.error(). I changed my calls to this and they show up in the log window now (as error messages). But this has the advantage that I can filter out all the warnings from the add-on builder itself, so using the error level for my debug messages is quite useful actually.

Comment: On a seemingly related note, the upgrade to add-on SDK 1.14 seems to have 'broken' (or discontinued) `alert()`

Comment: I haven't even dared to try `alert` from the chrome context. ;-)

Comment: Very important last step is to restart Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing `var aConsoleService = Cc...` just stick in the following and you can use everything:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');
```

can now do whatever, `console.log('blah')`, `console.time('rawr')`, `console.endTime('rawr')`, etc etc etc

Comment: Does `Cu.import` actually work? The examples I have are `Components.utils.import`

Comment: @dbreaux Usually devs do this shortcut: `Cu` is defined as `Components.utils` by going: `const {interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, classes: Cc} = Components;` and in addon-sdk they go: `var {Cu, Ci, Cc} = require('chrome');`

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness: in a bootstrapped, non-SDK-based addon, I had to add these two lines in bootstrap.js to have a faked console.log():

```
var aConsoleService = Cc["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"].getService(Ci.nsIConsoleService);
var console = {log:function(str){aConsoleService.logStringMessage(str);}}
```

Might come in handy for somebody else, I guess..

Comment: To quote from [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/) - "In Webkit browsers the console is built-in and the console property is always available. The Firefox console depends on Firebug (or other add-ons) being installed and switched on. IE7 has no console, IE8 has a console but the console property only exists when IE Developer Tools is started."

Answer (score 2):

I guess they changed something, now console.log isn't displayed. I use console.error for debugging, it still shows up in ctrl-shift-j.

This page say something about deprecation of Error Console and using Web Console instead. It's probably related.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIConsoleService

This doesn't require the sdk.